# Report of bitbucket and github pull and push

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-svn, bitbucket-api

I need a report of all pull and push by all team members.

Comment: Ooops sorry, by mistake i click on accept button, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You *could* use [GitHub webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) or [Bitbucket webhook](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html) to listen (and trace) push events.

But:

- there is no "clone/pull/fetch" events
- you wouldn't be sure of *who* did the push anyway.

A better setup would be for the team to push to a "git repo proxy" (an intermediate repo that you control), in which:

- you have **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html)** set up (gitolite, a simple perl script, can log *all* git-related operations -- clone, fetch, pull, push, ... -- , and *who* did said operations)
- you have a hook pushing automatically to GitHub/BitBucket (depending on the git repo proxy they are pushing to)

You can then extract the report from the gitolite logs from the server hosting those intermediate "git repos proxy" (proxy to GitHub, or proxy to Bitbucket).

Comment: thanks for your response, but I am using windows system and gitolite requires an unix system.

Comment: @GauravSachan You can setup a virtualbox in order to host those 2 git proxy repo. In that virtual machine, you will be able to use gitolite. The goal is to have an "exit point" that you control, and that you can audit.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
git log --author="username"  > log.log
```